# Python - Filtering dataframe based on 3 columns potentially containing a sought after value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a query of recent customer transactions and match potential primary phone, cellphone and work phone matches against a particular list of customers I have.

Essentially, I am taking one dataframe column (the list of customers I am trying to see if they had transactions recently) against the overall universe of all recent transactions (dataframe being transaction_data) and remove any row that does not have a match in either the primary phone, cellphone or workphone column,

Here is what I am currently trying to do but it only returns Falses across each column header and does not filter the dataframe by rows as I had hoped,

```
transaction_data[(transaction_data['phone'].isin(df['phone'])) | (transaction_data['cell'].isin(df['phone'])) | (transaction_data['workphone'].isin(df['phone']))].any()
```

I'm trying to return a dataframe containing rows of transactional records where there is a match on either primary phone, cellphone or workphone.

Is there a better way to do this perhaps? Or do I need a minor tweak on my code?

Comment: Does `transaction_data[transaction_data[['phone', 'cell', 'workphone']].isin(df['phone']).any(1)]` work?

Comment: It unfortunately does not. It'll retrieve an empty dataframe, I've done this exercise in Excel so I know there's roughly 300 matches but I can't seem to get any when I do it in Python,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing here is that applying the `.isin()` method of a Series to another Series will return a boolean Series.

In your example `transaction_data['phone']` is a Series, and also `df['phone']`. The return of this method will be a boolean Series containing the value `True` in a row which the value in `transaction_data['phone']` appears in `df['phone']` and `False` otherwise. This is similar for all applications of `isin()` method in your example.

And, good news! This boolean Series is exactly what is needed for slicing the dataframe. Therefor your code just need a small tweak. Just delete the `.any()` at the end of the line.

```
transaction_data[(transaction_data['phone'].isin(df['phone'])) | (transaction_data['cell'].isin(df['phone'])) | (transaction_data['workphone'].isin(df['phone']))]
```